# Javascript Unexpected control character(s) in regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

My ESlint throws the error 
`Unexpected control character(s) in regular expression: \x08  no-control-regex`
for my regular expression 
`let regex = new RegExp("^[0-9a-zA-Z \b]+$");`

If i remove `\b` from my regEx the error is not thrown. Why is this happening? How can i remove the error?

Comment: probably an option in eslint to ignore this *warning*, since `\b` in there is perfectly valid (though, how would you get a string that includes the backspace character?)

Comment: [I can't reproduce your problem](http://rextester.com/IKCW23373), but assuming backspace is included in general whitespace, then `\s` should also match backspace.  Actually, I'm not sure backspace is an actual character, and it should be noted that `\b` is a _word boundary_, not a character.

Comment: If you need `\b` you should probably disable this ESLint rule that is set by default https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-control-regex

Comment: Not tested but: I think that `\b` inside a character class is seen as the backspace character (\x08).

Comment: `how would I get a string that includes the backspace character` - did you want a backspace in a string? or do you mean how do you get a backspace into a regexp

Comment: @JaromandaX The above expression perfectly handles my requirement. I couldnt find any alternative regex for the same without causing an error by eslint

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte so replacing `\b` with `\x08` should fix my error?

Comment: unfortunately , that doesnt fix the issue either

Comment: sorry, you confused me with the `how would I get a string that includes the backspace character` ... didn't know if you meant in the RegExp constructor, or the string you are applying it to - I can't see how you would get a string with a backspace character in it to use that regexp on, to be honest

Comment: @NoushadPP: oh no, my comment was only to describe the meaning of `\b` in this particular context (inside a character class). I don't know what you are trying to achieve and why `\b` is included in the character class. But if you explain what your pattern is supposed to check, you will get more appropriate suggestions.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The rule [no-control-regex](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-control-regex) is on.

This rule is enabled by default when you inherit rules from `eslint:recommended`

```
"extends": "eslint:recommended"
```

Reason why it's enabled by default:

> Control characters are special, invisible characters in the ASCII range 0-31. These characters are rarely used in JavaScript strings so a regular expression containing these characters is most likely a mistake.

To disable this rule, add on your eslint config

```
"rules": {
  "no-control-regex": 0
}
```

Comment: Very interesting, but what a strange rule! (in particular if you consider characters like the tabulation, the carriage return, the newline and eventually the line feed that are very common characters).

Comment: "most likely a mistake"... Pfft... Silly.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Code with React. I tried editing package.json like this - "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app",
    "rules": {
      "no-control-regex": 0
    }
  } - but it had no effect.

Comment: Hi @DrorBar, try adding above each problematic line: // eslint-disable-next-line

Comment: I disagree this is the right answer. Disabling lint rule is like hiding the problem without fixing it. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69445581/1131246) for the proper way to fix the error.

Answer (score 4):

The reasons why ESLint throwing error:

1. Lint rule [no-control-regex](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-control-regex) is on.
2. The expression in string is not properly escaped and therefore contains control characters. See the following code:

```js
// This prints: ^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$
// Notice that the space character and \b is missing
console.log("^[0-9a-zA-Z \b]+$")
```

The right way to fix the error is to escape the string properly.

```js
let regex = new RegExp("^[0-9a-zA-Z \\b]+$");
```

Answer (score -2):

I got same issue, use `\\n` to replace `\n` that's all.